# How to concat two strings and use the result as a variable name in coldfusion?

Tags: concatenation, cfml, evaluate

I have a form which has many fields in the format of

- name="field-1"
- name="field-2"
- name="field-3"
- name="field-4"
- etc....

On the form action page, I would like to be able to use a loop and be able to use the index of the loop to concat with a string prefix like this `<cfset newField = "field-" & #index#>` and then use the `#Variables.newField#` to access the form field on the previous page.

I've been playing around with the `Evaluate()` function, but no luck.  I don't use ColdFusion much, so I may just be a little off on the syntax.

An example of how I am using it is:

```
<cfset newField = "form.field-" & #index#>
<input type="hidden" 
      name="field-<cfoutput>#index#</cfoutput>" 
      value="<cfoutput>Evaluate(Variables.newField)</cfoutput>">
```

Comment: It just outputs form.field-1, form.field-2 and so on.  I need the value stored in form.field-1, not the text "form.field-1".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have to use evaluate at all for this case. Just access the variables struct by key name.

```
<cfset newField = "form.field-" & index>
<cfset value = variables[newField]>
```

or just

```
<cfset value = variables["form.field-#index#"]>
```

or if you don't want to use an intermediary variable

```
<cfoutput>#variables["form.field-" & index]#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Bingo, I just had to change it to `<cfset value = form["field-#index#"]>`.  Thank you very much, and I have to wait another 5 minutes before I can give you credit, but I will. :-).

Comment: Awesome. Obviously, it works with any struct object - I was just using the structures you mentioned/used in the question.

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to set it to the `variables` scope. Within your loop, you can simply access the form field values using associative array notation directly from the `form` scope like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="field-<cfoutput>#index#</cfoutput>" 
value="<cfoutput>#form['field-' & index]#</cfoutput>">
```

For extra safety, it would be wise to check for the existence of each form field before trying to display it:

```
<cfif structKeyExists(form, 'field-' & index)>
    <!--- display field --->
</cfif>
```